# Calculate Next Audit Date between Audit Frequency and Last Audit Date field for Vendor Object

Tags: managed-package, formula-field

I am trying to calculate the Next Audit Year based on Audit Frequency field(which is a picklist with the following values: Annually, Every 2 years and Every 5 years) and the Last Audit Date which is a date field.

Is this possible? I was thinking the Next Audit Year could be calculated by creating a formula on the field. It is for vendor object.

How would I set up the formula up for this new field?

Comment: would you mind marking my answer as accepted if it worked for you?

Comment: Hello, So I tried the formula you provided and received an error mentioning that CASE function will not work. I also tried changing it from CASE to ISPICKLIST VAL. See below: YEAR(Last_Audit_Date__c) + ISPICKVAL(Audit_Frequency__c, "Annually", 1, "Every 2 years", 2, "Every 5 years", 5). See you added the number of years individually. The customer has the picklist as follows: Annually, Every 2 years, and Every 5 years.  Let me know your thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ADDYEARS` function in Salesforce, so you will need to use `ADDMONTHS`. So your formula would be:

`ADDMONTHS(Last_Audit_Date__c, CASE(Audit_Frequency__c, "Annually", 12, "Every 2 years", 24, "Every 5 years", 60, 12))`

If you just want the year, you could do:

`YEAR(Last_Audit_Date__c) + CASE(Audit_Frequency__c, "Annually", 1, "Every 2 years", 2, "Every 5 years", 5, 1)`

Comment: Hello, So I tried the formula you provided and received an error mentioning that CASE function will not work. I also tried changing it from CASE to ISPICKLIST VAL. See below: YEAR(Last_Audit_Date__c) + ISPICKVAL(Audit_Frequency__c, "Annually", 1, "Every 2 years", 2, "Every 5 years", 5)

Comment: I've edited my formula. Try it now? The last number in the CASE formula is the default value.

Comment: @Chantel did that work?

Comment: I ended up using the following formula my colleague assisted me with: DATE(YEAR(Last_Audit_Date__c) + IF(ISPICKVAL (Audit_Frequency__c, "Annually"),1, IF(ISPICKVAL (Audit_Frequency__c, "Every 2 years"), 2, IF(ISPICKVAL (Audit_Frequency__c, "Every 5 years"),5,0))), Month(Last_Audit_Date__c),DAY(Last_Audit_Date__c))

Comment: You could still use `CASE` there to make it more concise